# How to hash a password using an existing key in PCLCrypto?

Tags: xamarin.forms, password-encryption

I'm creating a mobile application that connects to a web service. It needs to login to the system using a password. The password is stored on the server as a MD5 hashed password that was hashed using this method:

```
    Byte[] Initial = <Key goes here>
    MD5CryptoServiceProvider Provider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
    List<Byte> Encoding = new List<Byte>(Initial);
    Encoding.AddRange(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inputString));
    return Convert.ToBase64String(Provider.ComputeHash(Encoding.ToArray()));
```

The key and code to hash the password on the web application cannot be used in my Xamarin PCL project because it's not possible to use the 'MD5CryptoServiceProvider' in Xamarin PCL.

I need to create an equivalent method in the xamarin application to hash the password, before it's compared to the web service version.

To do this I have chose PCLCrypto but I can't seem to find anywhere to include the same key that was used to originally encrypt the password.

This is the Xamarin code:

```
    Byte[] Initial = <the same key as was used to originally cache it>


    // step 1, calculate MD5 hash from input
    var hasher = WinRTCrypto.HashAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(HashAlgorithm.Md5);

    byte[] inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputString);
    byte[] hash = hasher.HashData(inputBytes);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < hash.Length; i++)
    {
        sb.Append(hash[i].ToString("X2"));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why dont you use directly Base64 class of android? In that case you have to implement it for each plateform but you wont have headache.. Just an advice..

Comment: Because it's a PCL project.

Comment: Ok.. we are talking about xamarin forms project right?
In each plateform you create 
comparepasswords(userpwd,hashedpwd)
{
  //hash userpwd and compare
  //return true or false
}
use dependancy service to call function..
Thus, you will be able to use base64 class..

Comment: @Mr.Koçak Do you have an example of the code?

Comment: I also found a link that can be interesting for you.. I didnt check the content
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40557467/xamarin-pclcrypto-sha256-give-different-hash

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution but i use plateform specific code.
In xamarin.forms part you implement an interface like for example:

```
public interface SpecificCodes
    {
        Boolean comparePasswords(String userPassword,String DBPassword);
    }
```

In xamarin.android you create a class which implements interface

```
[assembly:Dependency(typeof(MyProject.Droid.Code.SpecificPartsAndroid))]
namespace MyProject.Droid.Code
{

...
   public class SpecificPartsAndroid: SpecificCodes
   {
      public Boolean comparePasswords(String userPassword, String DBPassword)
      {
            byte[] dig = hash(new Java.Lang.String(userPassword).GetBytes("UTF-8"),"MD5");
            byte[] res=Base64.Decode(DBPassword,Base64Flags.Default);
            return String.Compare(dig.ToString(),res.ToString())==0?true:false;
      }
private static byte[] hash (byte[] toHash, String algorithm)
        {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.GetInstance(algorithm);
            return md.Digest(toHash);
        }
   }
}
```

In xamarin.ios do the same
And then to call your function use the code below in Xamarin.forms

```
DependencyService.Get<SpecificCodes>().comparePasswords(pwdUser, pwdHashed);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Dont forget [assembly:Dependency(typeof(MyProject.Droid.Code.SpecificPartsAndroid))] line..

Answer (score -1):

Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iIterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as PBKDF2, password_hash, Bcrypt and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Protecting your users is important, please use secure password methods.

See [How to securely hash passwords, The Theory](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/211/how-to-securely-hash-passwords/31846#31846) on Security Stackexchange.

See OWASP (Open Web Application Security Project) [Password Storage Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet#Leverage_an_adaptive_one-way_function).

See [Modern, Secure, Salted Password Hashing Made Simple](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016#legacy-hashes)

See [Toward Better Password Requirements](http://www.slideshare.net/jim_fenton/toward-better-password-requirements) by Jim Fenton:

Comment: I cannot change the web service so it needs to hash with the exact same results unfortunately.